# MS Bot Framework, how to geolocate user on Skype

Tags: geolocation, skype, botframework

Is there any way to get the location of the Skype user *with his/her consent*?
In the samples there is an example of [EchoLocation Dialog for Facebook messenger](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/EchoBot/EchoLocationDialog.cs).

Is something like that possible in Skype? The would ask the user to send the location, this would not happen without consent.

Getting the user's IP address would be enough too, I could work out the location from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of yet, Skype does not yet support sending of location.

Answer (score 0):

Skype does not let you do that as of now due to privacy issues.