# Prompt for user location on Skype bot

Tags: botframework, skype, azure-bot-service, skype-bots

I've recently discovered it's possible to send location in all of skype new client apps.
I tried to send it proactively as a user to the bot and it worked (received the geolocation through the message entities)

My question is whether it's possible to prompt the user to send a location with a button or quick reply?

[image: location sharing]

I've seen it wasn't possible two years ago, but it seems like it might have changed

[MS Bot Framework, how to geolocate user on Skype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736061/ms-bot-framework-how-to-geolocate-user-on-skype/40754098#40754098)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Skype bots does not currently support sharing geolocation of the users. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe what you are referring to is the "Send Location" functionality in [mobile versions](https://blogs.skype.com/tips/2016/06/23/how-to-share-your-location-with-skype-for-mobile/) of the Skype (e.g. iOS, Android). That is a useful feature on user's end to send user's current location, and it basically sends a text (e.g. 700 Clark Ave, St. Louis, MO 63102, United States) which is reverse-geocoded from the user's current location.

If you'd like to retrieve your bot users' locations, independent of the device they are using, ["botbuilder-location"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-location#handling-returned-location) library offers a good workaround.

Of course, you can develop similar approaches using other geocoding services (e.g. Google Geocoding API).

Comment: Yes I do, it seems to be available also on Desktop versions (Linux).
The question is if it does exist, is it possible to prompt the user for it?
 A workaround of sending the address is not a good fit for bots being used "on the go" (inconvenient)